# An example of the fact that from measurability of a random process does not follow measurability of its integral

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, lebesgue-integral, examples-counterexamples, filtrations

Let {$ \xi _t(\omega), t\in[0,\infty)$} be a random process and $ \xi _t(\omega)\in \{\mathfrak F_t\}$ (some filtration). If  $ \xi _t(\omega) $ is $ \mathfrak F_t $ measurable then  $\int_0^t\xi _s(\omega)L(ds)$ not necessarily $ \mathfrak F_t $ measurable. I am looking for  a process, that will demonstrate this statement. Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: What is $L$...? And what exactly do you mean by $\xi_t(\omega)$ is measurable (measurable with respect to which variable? $\omega$ or $t$? or jointly measurable)?

Comment: @saz Lebesgue measure

Comment: I see. What makes you believe that such a process exist?

Comment: @saz  I think such an example could be  Heaviside function. But I'm not sure.